# How can clear enqueue jobs in backburner with beanstalkd in rails while updating any object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, beanstalkd

while creating a campaign (model) in my project I have enqueue jobs for Backburner with the help of beanstalkd in rails. As describe below :

```
Backburner::Worker.enqueue(DeviceJob, [ad, campaign.id, "Ad"], :delay => add_job.to_i.minutes)
```

that is working fine but when i update campaign then previous jobs will remain with current jobs. but, i want to remove all previous jobs for current campaign.

In delayed_job, we can done with active records table.
In resque, we can use redis server.

But in backburner, How it could be possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would either use the **beaneater API** directly or use a tool like **[beanstalkd_view gem](https://github.com/denniskuczynski/beanstalkd_view)** which provides a web-based management UI.

```
beanstalk = Beaneater::Pool.new(['localhost:11300'])
tube = beanstalk.tubes["some-tube"]
while tube.peek(:ready)
  job = tube.reserve
  job.delete
end
beanstalk.close
```

Comment: Thanks. but in my case we need to have a enqueue record for each campaign while creation. because, after update campaign, we want previous jobs replace with updated jobs details.